# Is there a way to fix 403 error message when you check page speed?

Tags: google-search-console, pagespeed-insights

My website works perfectly well, but when I try to check my page speed insight I get the following error message.
**Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 403)**

I resent my XML sitemap to Google search console, but I still get the error message. Please, is there anybody who knows how to solve this? My website is a Wordpress website.

Comment: What is the URL for your website?

Answer (score 0):

Could be your server blocking it due to running the test too many times. Check with your hosting provider and ask them to unblock Google Lighthouse, or see some info here what to look for in your logs https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/55087112?hl=en